# Implementing a Spinner inside a Custom AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a spinner inside of a custom alertdialog box, but I keep getting a **NullPointer Exception**. any ideas?

> The NullPointer Exception occurs at the line:
>   `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` where spinner is null.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.priority_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        builder.show();
```

Comment: From which line of code is the NPE originating?

Comment: The NullPointer Exception occurs at the line: spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
where spinner is null... I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Search for `Spinner` in `dialoglayout`

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a stacktrace so we may know WHERE your Nullpointer exception occurs :) .

Cheers,

Ready4Android

P.s. Grrr seems I cant write comments :O  otherwise this would have been a comment.

Comment: The NullPointer Exception occurs at the line: spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
where spinner is null... I don't know why.